# convert array in proper format to show in Google chart

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts

i implement google dount chart now I try to set data using ajax. in google don't chart except data like this.

```
 ['Category', 'Amount'],
 ['Photos',     22],
 ['Videos',      9],
 ['Free Space',  9]
```

But when I try to make an array like this it's show different format like this.

```
["title", "receiptAmount", "Expense category", "50"]
```

so what can I do to convert in above format. i try with so many way to convert this but I didn't get any success on this I show what can I try with the code.

```
var arrValues = [];
arrValues = ['title', 'receiptAmount'];       
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
{
  arrValues.push(data[i]['title'],data[i]['receiptAmount']);
  dataArray = arrValues;
 }
 console.log(dataArray);
```

Please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to push **array** to **array**:

```
var arrValues = [];
arrValues.push(['title', 'receiptAmount']);
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    arrValues.push(
        [data[i]['title'], data[i]['receiptAmount']]
    );
}
console.log(arrValues);
```

Comment: Please, ask another question with your new problem, do not create discussion in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create array of arrays like this:

```
// var arrValues = [];
var arrValues = [['title', 'receiptAmount']];       
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
{
  arrValues.push([data[i]['title'],data[i]['receiptAmount']]);
  dataArray = arrValues;
 }
 console.log(dataArray);
```

Hope it helps!